# Can Java's random function be zero?

Tags: java, random

Just out of curiosity, can Math.random() ever be zero?

For example, if I were to have:

```
while (true){
  if (Math.random() == 0)
    return 1;
}
```

Would I ever actually get a return of one? There's also rounding error to consider because Math.random() returns a double.

I ask because my CS professor stated that random() goes from 0 to 1 inclusive, and I always thought it was exclusive.

Comment: Was your CS professor talking about Java, or rather about a purely mathematical random function with equal distribution? Because such a function, for the real numbers range from 0 to 1, doesn't have any probability for 0. Also not for 1. Nor for 0.5: A probability can only be assigned to an interval. But that's of course not true for a discrete number range as we have here in Java... (I'm sure, that's what he meant ;)

Comment: Just check the documentation for Math.random(), it will indicate if it's inclusive or exclusive.

Comment: No rounding error here, by the way. You'll just get a `double` with 53 uniformly-distributed pseudo-random bits in its mantissa.

Comment: This post got featured on a YT video regarding a Minecraft bug: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JFHGiv6qeX8

Comment: I think I actually got zero once. I was writing a script to move an array of circles around at a random speed and one happened to be stationary among the surrounding chaos

Answer (score 23, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random()), "Returns a double value with a positive sign, greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0."  This means it can be zero.

As [Hank wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065554/can-javas-random-function-be-zero/3065580#3065580), it *is* exclusive on the upper boundary (can never be 1), so maybe that's where your confusion comes from :-).

Answer (score 40):

Yes, it *really* can be. `Math.random()` creates a global `java.util.Random`-generator with seed `(System.currentTimeMillis() ^ 0x5DEECE66DL) & ((1L << 48) - 1)` and calls `nextDouble()` for it. If its seed reaches state `107048004364969L`(and it will, since `java.util.Random` has full period), the next `double` generated will be `0.0`. 
Though with bad luck you could end up with the wrong parity in the cycle, because 
`Random.nextDouble()` advances the state twice. With little less bad luck you could have to generate 2^47 random numbers before the loop terminates, as I didn't find any other seeds that give `0.0`.

The seed advances as if by `seed = (seed * 0x5DEECE66DL + 0xBL) & ((1L << 48) - 1);`
and doubles are generated using 26 and 27 upper bits of two consecutive seed values. In the example the two next seed values will be `0L` and `11L`.

If you manage to create the global generator with `System.currentTimeMillis()==107038380838084L`, your code returns immediately. You can simulate this with:

`java.util.Random k = new java.util.Random(107038380838084L);`
`System.out.println(k.nextDouble()==0);`

Comment: And, if you think it looks too suspicious to hit zero in the very next try, use `new java.util.Random(164311266871034L)`, and you'll hit it in two tries. Or `new java.util.Random(240144965573432L)`, and three tries. Or `new java.util.Random(881498)`, and you'll get a zero after 376050 calls to `nextDouble`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The question asks for java's `Math.random` which (when first called) creates a single new pseudorandom-number generator, exactly as if by the expression `new java.util.Random()`, that in turn is used as `Random.nextDouble()` thereafter for all calls to `Math.random()`. `nextDouble()` works as: `return (((long)next(26) << 27) + next(27)) / (double)(1L << 53);` (and incorrectly in early versions of java as: `return (((long)next(27) << 27) + next(27)) / (double)(1L << 54);`). Here `next` returns the requested topmost bits `(int)(seed >>> (48 - bits))`.

Comment: If anybody wants to try this, run your program on 29.11.5361 at 3:33:58.084. It just takes a bit of waiting. Actually, I wonder how many programs will do something unexpected on that day. It's like the 2038 problem. Except that I highly doubt that `System.currentTimeMillis` will still be used in it's current form in 5361.

Answer (score 10):

It is perfectly possible that it will never return exactly zero. Java's included PRNG is a 48-bit LCG from which only 32 bits are ever used. For all 53 bits of a `double` mantissa to be zero, you'll essentially need at least *one* call to `next()` where the upper 32 bits are zero and another where most of them are. (If I'm not mistaken, I'd say this won't ever happen with how the generator works, but it's late, I'm tired, and I won't bet much on it.)

Since the method documentation explicitly states how random numbers are obtained there is also little leeway for other implementations of the Java runtime to yield different results. The *contract* might say that the number you get is from [0, 1). But in practice there are quite a number of values you'll never hit (because you need two successive values from a generator that foribly yields a linear dependency between successive values – there are only 48 bits of state. You can't generate all different 53-bit combinations from that – at least not how it's done.).

Of course, since `Math.random()` automatically seeds a static `Random` instance, we might also have to consider the seed here, which *may* need to be very specific for a test case to work out. And that might mean that that exact point in time could be a few decades or millennia away.

Comment: As a practical counterexample, Angs' [answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4371484/733345) shows a specific PRNG state where the generator will return exactly that combination of `next()`s.

Answer (score 9):

It's inclusive of the zero, exclusive of the one, e.g., `[0, 1)` or `0 <= x < 1` depending on which notation you prefer.

Answer (score 6):

In theory, it can return the value zero.

In practice, you might have to wait an extremely long time to get *exactly* zero.  If the random number generator is implemented well, it has at least 56 bits of internal state (otherwise all the bits of the returned result will not be random).  And that implies, if the distribution of the values produced by random is flat, that you have at most one chance in 2^56 of getting back a value all of whose bits are zero.  That's roughly 10^-19.  I wouldn't hold my breath.

(Others have rightfully observed that as documented, in theory [and presumably in practice] it cannot return the value 1.0).

Comment: You could make the same case for any combination of the 56 bits of internal state.  If the random number generator is implemented well, the chance of returning zero ought to be the same as any other discrete double.

Comment: @Gilbert: Agreed, but the question was specifically "can it be zero?"

Comment: Java uses a 48-bit LCG of which only 32 bits are used. This is also noted in the documentation for `nextLong()` that it simply *can't* generate all possible `long` values. Same goes (obviously) for `double`s.

Comment: @Johannes: OK, so the random numbers aren't as random as they could be (32 bits instead of 56). Seems like a pretty dumb implementation; what's the point of a random number generator that isn't very random? Still only 1 chance in 2^32 or less than 1 in a billion.

Comment: People have been building random number generators for decades; there was tons of theory when I looked at in a numerical algorithms class back in the 70s. How to build a good one was easily available when Java came out.  Sounds to me like they simply did a lousy job.  Yes, you can code your own.  The point of a framework or library is to arrange it so you don't have to do that.

Answer (score 2):

From the java API.

> Returns a double value with a positive sign, greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random()

So yes it can be.

Answer (score 1):

Math.random() is [documented](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) to return "a double value with a positive sign, greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0"
That is, inclusive of 0.0 but exclusive of 1.0

Answer (score 1):

it is also possible, in a compliant JRE implementation, that it NEVER returns 0.

Comment: it is also possible, given a truly random generator and due to the nature of randomness that, in a compliant JRE implementation, it ALWAYS returns 0.

Comment: @Stephen: Read the Javadocs (which, for the standard library are considered part of the specification). Any implementation of `Math.random()` *has to* use `java.util.Random` whcih in turn *has to be* a specific LCG.

Comment: @Johannes: I read the javadocs, and linked to them in my answer. My point, relating to irreputable's answer, is that while it's true it is *possible* that a 0.0 is never returned it is also possible that a 0.0 is *always* returned. To be compliant it must be possible for any value *x* where 0.0 <= *x* < 1.0 to be returned, including the improbable cases where 0 is never returned or 0 is always returned.
I first read irreputable's statement as "you could write a compliant JRE that would never-ever return 0." which is wrong, but the *improbable* case that 0 is never returned *is* correct.

Answer (score 1):

It's theoretically possible for math.random() to return a zero value, but in the real world, you can count on it virtually never happening.

I once ran my pc for a week straight waiting for one, it generated about ten trillion random numbers, no zeros.

But more directly, it is practically exclusive both ways.

Comment: Not theoretically possible, but completely possible. See the answer provided by @Angs and the comments.

Comment: I ran it for a month once, never got a zero.

Answer (score 0):

From http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html

*random() Returns a double value with a positive sign, greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0.*

Yes, it can be zero, but not 1. In other words, prefer the Java documentation over your CS professor =)